# How PayPal charges the transaction?

Tags: android, paypal

I want to build a cash-in/cash-out system with PayPal to work with a digital currency for my marketplace.
How can I handle the fees of PayPal? As merchant account I read that I will always need to pay the fees (cash-in / cash-out).

Is there a way that the customer pays the feeds for cashing-in?

Comment: Why not just increase prices by 10-11% (PP fees)? Fees immediately reduces the amount of money you get, so you don't have to actively do some action to pay those fees because them are "passively" decurted from the total amount

Comment: Yes, But PayPal charges are different base on currency and transfer rates.
@emandt

Comment: So? PP allow payments not money exchange, so the "algorithm"/behaviour is different. If you accept money in your EUR wallet all worldwide moneys are instantly exchanged in EUR and then (after decurted from fees) added to your wallet. For some country fees are X, for another Y and for others Z. But if you have in mind Taxes then the thing is very different and difficult because it follows Law rules of each country.